# facebook django type select for many-to-many fields

Tags: django, facebook, django-models, django-forms

I am wondering if there is maybe a way with django to display bring in extra data into the display of `CheckboxSelectMultiple` ie `avatar` or `first_name` or `last_name`

With the `manytomany` field its really good that a user can check their options and proceed, but what sometimes it might be that a user has the same information twice, ie a name that is the same, or a reference to something that is the same.

Facebook has a very nice style when you want to share something with somebody you can select that user and see their avatar at the same time, so if you have two friends with the same name and surname, you can always distinguish them by their avatar.

is there some way with the `__init__` that this can be achieved, or do you guys have any pointers on achieving this in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The answer linked to below has an example of a custom `SelectMultiple` widget which makes the objects being selected available for use in presenting further details to the user in the widget's `render()` method:

- [Formsets with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218555/formsets-with-checkboxes/4248407#4248407)