# Problem to create radio choice form with django and bootstrap classes

Tags: python, django, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a form with radio button choices with Django. The website is designed in bootstrap 4 and for some reason, the buttons dissapear when the custom-control-input class is applied.

I have started with a static template that is rendering perfectly. The code for these button groups is the following:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Sexo</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sexo1" name="sexoRadios">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="sexo1">Mujer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sexo2" name="sexoRadios">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="sexo2">Hombre</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To create the form in Django, I have added this lines to the forms.py file:

```
sexo_choices=[('hombre','Hombre'),
            ('mujer','Mujer')]
sexo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=sexo_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect(
        attrs={'class':'custom-control-input'}
    ))
```

This makes the radio buttons to dissapear for some reason. If I analyze the HTML created by django, it seems quite similar to the static web.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Sexo</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <label for="id_sexo_0"><input type="radio" name="sexo" value="hombre" class="custom-control-input" id="id_sexo_0" required>Hombre</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <label for="id_sexo_1"><input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer" class="custom-control-input" id="id_sexo_1" required>Mujer</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I inspect the object with Google Chrome, I observe that the input tag has the following CSS attributes:

```
.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It seems the problem comes from the class of the label tag. Is there a way to assign a class to the label?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem. This is how I left the HTML template:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Sexo</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    {% for radio in form.sexo %}
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            {{ radio.tag }}
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you anyway. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help someone: [How to custom checkbox and radio in Django using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484888/how-to-custom-checkbox-and-radio-in-django-using-bootstrap)

**template.html**

```
<!-- radio -->
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.field_name.label_tag }}
    {% for pk, choice in form.field_name.field.widget.choices %}
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input id="id_{{form.field_name.name}}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{form.field_name.name}}" type="{{form.field_name.field.widget.input_type}}" value="{{pk}}" class="custom-control-input"
         {% ifequal form.field_name.data pk.0 %}
           checked="checked"
         {% endifequal %}/>
        <label for="id_{{form.field_name.name}}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="custom-control-label">{{ choice }}</label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- checkbox -->
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.field_name.label_tag }}
    {% for pk, choice in form.field_name.field.widget.choices %}
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input id="id_{{form.field_name.name}}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{form.field_name.name}}" type="{{form.field_name.field.widget.input_type}}" value="{{pk}}" class="custom-control-input"
         {% ifequal form.field_name.data pk.0 %}
           checked="checked"
         {% endifequal %}/>
        <label for="id_{{form.field_name.name}}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="custom-control-label">{{ choice }}</label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image: My result]